# How to use Moq to return a List of data or values?

Tags: c#, testing, moq, using

Can anyone tell me how to return List of data using mock object using Moq framework and assigning the so returned list of data to another List<> variable.??

Comment: I am using a mock object to call a method which returns values in List<> form.

Comment: please add some sample code. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual List<int> GimmeSomeData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestSomeClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void HowToMockAList()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<SomeClass>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.GimmeSomeData()).Returns(() => new List<int> {1, 2, 3});
        var resultList = mock.Object.GimmeSomeData();
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<int>{1,2,3},resultList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Richard Banks gave the correct answer. For completeness, if you want to use [Moq v4 functional specifications](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/old-style-imperative-mocks-vs-moq-functional-specifications/) and get rid of the .Object:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

    ISomeInterface implementation =
        Mock.Of<ISomeInterface>(si => si.GimmeSomeData() == list);

    List<int> resultList = implementation.GimmeSomeData();

    foreach (int i in resultList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    List<int> GimmeSomeData();
}
```