# xUnit converting IDictionary to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, moq, xunit.net

I've been searching the web for a way to make an `IEnumerable` in the `Setup` of a Mock by converting the Values of my `IDictionary` to it (either directly or conversion from '=`List` to `IEnumerable`). However I have only come across the latter.

Inspiration Sources:

1. [IEnumerable<object> a = new IEnumerable<object>(); Can i do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606407/ienumerableobject-a-new-ienumerableobject-can-i-do-this)
2. [Convert dictionary with List to IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451810/convert-dictionary-with-list-to-ienumerable)
3. [Convert dictionary of any type to IEnumerable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060838/convert-dictionary-of-any-type-to-ienumerable-collection)
4. [How to use Moq to return a List of data or values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855755/how-to-use-moq-to-return-a-list-of-data-or-values)

   ```
   public class UserServiceTests
   {
       private Mock<IUserRepository> _userRep { get; set; }

       // fake app repository to get data from
       private IDictionary<int, User> _userRepData { get; set; }

       private UserService _sut { get; set; }

       public UserServiceTests()
   {
       _userRepData = new Dictionary<int, User>();

       _userRep = new Mock<IUserRepository>();

       // Been able to create the proper list using:
       // List<User> usersList = _userRepData.Values.ToList<User>(); 
       // IEnumerable<User> users = appsList.AsEnumerable();
       // So I am looking for away to replicate this in my setup method
       // Obviously know the below is not the correct syntax.
       _userRep.Setup(r => r.GetUsers()).Returns(() => new IEnumerable<User> {_userRepData.Values.ToList<User>} );

       _sut = new UserService(_userRep.Object);
   }

   [Fact]
   public void GetUsers_succeeds_at_getting_all_users_from_repository()
   {
       User user1 = new User();
       User user2 = new User();

       _userRepData.Add(1, user1);
       _userRepData.Add(2, user2);

       IEnumerable<User> users = new User[] { user1, user2 };

       _sut.GetUsers().Should().BeSameAs(users); // Note: fluentassertions
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: You need to understand what interfaces are.

Comment: `_userRep.Setup(r => r.GetUsers()).Returns(() => _userRepData.Values.ToList().AsEnumerable());` does that work?

Comment: ```_userRep.Setup(r => r.GetUsers()).Returns(() => _userRepData.Values);```

Answer (score 1):

`Values` already implements `IEnumerable<T>`.
You can return it directly; you don't need to create anything.

Comment: He might need to cast it, though.

Comment: @phoog: No; types are implicitly convertible to interfaces they implement. (and the compile-time type of that property is `ICollection<TValue>`)

Comment: but type inference won't necessarily infer that the object should be converted, will it?

Comment: @phoog: That depends on the signature of the method he's passing the lambda to.

Comment: Exactly.  So, depending on that signature, he might need to cast it.

Comment: @SLaks For reference the signature is `public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()`. Nothing special.